# Call web api method

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Can we call web api with Https protocol instead of Http ?? If yes, then how can we ?

I have tried with Https; But it is not calling my web api method.

Any help on this appreaciated.

Comment: @MickyDuncan Have checked calling URL with https and also added the SSL property ??

Comment: I would have though WebAPI is not tied specifically to HTTPS but rather becomes an infrastructure choice at rollout allowing either HTTP or HTTPs?

Comment: @MickyDuncan Means you are saying we cannot call with https ??

Comment: Not at all.  [This article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api) explains how to enable SSL (therefor HTTPS) with Web API

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [1]

The steps are rather involved and I'm not sure if all can be summarised here.

**Disclaimer:** This answer most likely suffers from *[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)*

All is revealed in the link below but essentially:

1. Create a certificate for the purpose of SSL
2. Add a HTTPS binding to IIS
3. Update URLs to use the new HTTPS address

**More**

[1] [Working with SSL in Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api)